# MQTT Implementation Issue (Dale Lane Example)

Tags: java, android, mqtt

I am running into an issue with the implementation of the Dale Lane MQTT solution.

I cannot seem to figure out how to retrieve the published message from the MQTT Client I am using.

I am not sure if I am utilizing the the onReceive() method incorrectly, but for now all I would like to do is log the broadcasted messages.

http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599

The service I have implemented is exactly as listed here, I have no errors.

```
    public class MQTTNotifier extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  String preferenceBrokerHost, preferenceBrokerTopic;

  private StatusUpdateReceiver statusUpdateIntentReceiver;
  private MQTTMessageReceiver messageIntentReceiver;
  private EditText etBroker, etTopic;

  Button btnSubscribe, btnStopService;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mqttnotifier);
    initValues();
    // startService();
  }

  private void initValues() {

    btnSubscribe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubscribe);
    btnSubscribe.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnStopService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStopService);
    btnStopService.setOnClickListener(this);



    // if statement to see if sharedpreferences exist, if so reopen recievers
    /*
     * statusUpdateIntentReceiver = new StatusUpdateReceiver(); IntentFilter intentSFilter = new
     * IntentFilter(MQTTService.MQTT_STATUS_INTENT); registerReceiver(statusUpdateIntentReceiver,
     * intentSFilter);
     * 
     * messageIntentReceiver = new MQTTMessageReceiver(); IntentFilter intentCFilter = new
     * IntentFilter(MQTTService.MQTT_MSG_RECEIVED_INTENT); registerReceiver(messageIntentReceiver,
     * intentCFilter);
     */


  }

  public class StatusUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Bundle notificationData = intent.getExtras();
      String newStatus = notificationData.getString(MQTTService.MQTT_STATUS_MSG);


    }
  }
  public class MQTTMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Bundle notificationData = intent.getExtras();
      String newTopic = notificationData.getString(MQTTService.MQTT_MSG_RECEIVED_TOPIC);
      String newData = notificationData.getString(MQTTService.MQTT_MSG_RECEIVED_MSG);
      Log.e("NEW TOPIC", newTopic);
      Log.e("NEW DATA", newData);


    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(statusUpdateIntentReceiver);
    unregisterReceiver(messageIntentReceiver);

  }

  private void startService() {
    Intent svc = new Intent(this, MQTTService.class);
    startService(svc);
  }

  private void stopService() {
    Intent svc = new Intent(this, MQTTService.class);
    stopService(svc);
  }

  @Override
  public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
      NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
          (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      mNotificationManager.cancel(MQTTService.MQTT_NOTIFICATION_UPDATE);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.btnSubscribe:

        etBroker = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBroker);
        etTopic = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTopic);
        preferenceBrokerHost = etBroker.getText().toString().trim();
        preferenceBrokerTopic = etBroker.getText().toString().trim();

        createSharedPreferences(preferenceBrokerHost, preferenceBrokerTopic);
        establishRecievers();
        startService();
        break;

      case R.id.btnStopService:
        stopService();
    }

  }

  private void createSharedPreferences(String broker, String topic) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MQTTService.APP_ID, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("broker", broker);
    editor.putString("topic", topic);
    editor.commit();

  }

  private void establishRecievers() {
    statusUpdateIntentReceiver = new StatusUpdateReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentSFilter = new IntentFilter(MQTTService.MQTT_STATUS_INTENT);
    registerReceiver(statusUpdateIntentReceiver, intentSFilter);


    messageIntentReceiver = new MQTTMessageReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentCFilter = new IntentFilter(MQTTService.MQTT_MSG_RECEIVED_INTENT);
    registerReceiver(messageIntentReceiver, intentCFilter);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you're ever registering your receivers.

Comment: How so? I believe that is what I am doing inside establishRecievers()? I could be wrong though.

Comment: No.  I see you're doing it in the onClick now.  I'm not sure why you're not getting messages.  Are you sure your broker is getting them?  Can this app publish messages?

Comment: I don't know Dale Lane client, but did you check in some way you correctly connected to the broker and stay connected during your Activity lifecycle? In some of my tests with MQTT, sometimes I had to connect twice before reach a stable state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was in regards to a simple mistake that was in regards to this line.

```
    preferenceBrokerTopic = etBroker.getText().toString().trim();
```

I corrected the issue and now it corrects properly because it was not subscribing to the correct topic.

```
preferenceBrokerTopic = etTopic.getText().toString().trim();
```